autoinstall in cloud-init stops with question "Continue with autoinstall? (yes|no)"?
With the ISO ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso, I'm using this cloud-init script for an auto installation:
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: dns
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    install-server: yes
chpasswd:
  expire: false
ssh_pwauth: True

But the installation stops with this question:

How can I auto confirm with a yes that question? Thanks!

It says right above that: "Add autoinstall to your kernel command line to avoid this"

Is there not a way to do with cloud-init then?

I think this part is due to subiquity, not cloud-init itself: https://canonical-subiquity.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/explanation/zero-touch-autoinstall.html#zero-touch-deployment-with-autoinstall

This solved this question without rebuild the ISO:
Ubuntu 20.04:
#cloud-config
runcmd:
 - [eval, 'echo $(cat /proc/cmdline) "autoinstall" > /root/cmdline']
 - [eval, 'mount -n --bind -o ro /root/cmdline /proc/cmdline']
 - [eval, 'snap restart subiquity.subiquity-service']

autoinstall:
    version: 1
    identity:
        hostname: hack-nation
        username: superb-hacker
        password: $hashed

Ubuntu 22.04:
#cloud-config
runcmd:
  - [eval, 'echo $(cat /proc/cmdline) "autoinstall" > /root/cmdline']
  - [eval, 'mount -n --bind -o ro /root/cmdline /proc/cmdline']
  - [eval, 'snap restart subiquity.subiquity-server']
  - [eval, 'snap restart subiquity.subiquity-service']
...

